# EKS ALB Ingress address is given, but loading address does not work

Tags: dns, amazon-eks, amazon-route53, aws-application-load-balancer

Hi I've successfully setup an ALB controller and an ingress to one of my containers.

[image]

But when I route to my address in a browser it gives me this error
[image]

Is there something more that I need to do to connect to this? I was reading some AWS guides and I think that I should be able to route to this address without doing anything in Route53?

Below is the code for my helm chart

```
datahub-frontend:
  enabled: true
  image:
    repository: linkedin/datahub-frontend-react
    tag: "v0.8.31"
  ingress:
    enabled: true
    annotations:
      kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
      alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
      alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: instance
      alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn: arn:aws:acm:ap-southeast-2:601628467906:certificate/4a862e82-d098-4e27-9eb7-c8221df9e0cd
      alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/inbound-cidrs: 0.0.0.0/0
      alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTP": 80}, {"HTTPS":443}]'
      alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.ssl-redirect: '{"Type": "redirect", "RedirectConfig": { "Protocol": "HTTPS", "Port": "443", "StatusCode": "HTTP_301"}}'
    hosts:
      - host: datahub.hughnguyen.link
        redirectPaths:
          - path: /*
            name: ssl-redirect
            port: use-annotation
        paths:
          - /*
```

Comment: It looks like you are listening on port 80 only, but you have a redirect rule that is sending all port 80 requests to 443. Have you tried to delete or disable that rule?

Comment: how do i make it listen on port 443? Sorry which rule should I try disabling? the redirect or the listen-ports?

Comment: I have this very similar issue. Cannot access the address on the ingress directly. Adding a CNAME record to route 53 however works.